# Chrome Version 102.0.5005.63 (Official Build) (64-bit) invalidate session after 30 seconds

Tags: google-chrome

We are seeing a really weird issue with our production site where after 30 seconds it appears that the session is invalidated in the Chrome and Edge browsers. We don't see any errors in the chrome inspect console.

We saw this behavior on 25MAY2022 right around when chrome 102 got pushed to the browsers at 5pm. IF we use inspect and turn off the cache then we don't see any issues with loading the site and everything operates fine.

FireFox works fine.

I'm using chrome 101.0.4951.61 against the same site on my android 11 phone and I cannot reproduce the issue.

Are there any new features in 102 we could turn off to see if a specific new security check might be at play?

Answer (score 0):

My team is experiencing a similar issue when calling our API.  If you go to chrome://flags/#private-network-access-send-preflights, and disable it, does that resolve your issue?  If it does, then adding this header to your site may resolve the issue:

Access-Control-Request-Private-Network: true

We are currently doing pre-prod testing which is so far promising.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/

[Chrome ERROR_TIMED_OUT in latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400675/chrome-error-timed-out-in-latest-version)