# Chrome ERROR_TIMED_OUT in latest version

Tags: angular, google-chrome

We have an angular application (served using Tomcat web server) that makes "XHR" requests to "Express" (Node v14) server. Both the web server and app server are hosted on-premise. After updating Chrome from 101.x to 102.0.5005.63 (Mac) and 102.0.5005.61 (Win), we are seeing intermittent API failures in our web application. The "Status" in dev tools shows as "(failed)" for these "xhr" and "prefetch" requests. Console log says "net::ERR_TIMED_OUT". However there are no such intermittent errors when the API calls are made from Postman or from Chrome v102.x. I also tested in "Safari" and "Edge" and there is no error there. Can someone help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling "Send Private Network Access preflights" by visiting chrome://flags/#private-network-access-send-preflights

If it fixes the problem - your server should respond properly to "Access-Control-Request-Private-Network: true" preflight requests

More info: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/

Comment: That worked. That link says this is for public to private network requests. In my case everything is intranet and that is why I am still wondering what exactly was the change.

Comment: If you see time-out errors for the private network preflight requests in Chrome dev tools, then turn off the "Reduce waiting time for Private Network Access preflights response" flag in `chrome://flags/#private-network-access-send-preflights`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a temporary issue. [See here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1329248).

Answer (score 0):

We were getting the same with an external website (Netlify) then making internal API calls. We 'fixed' it by enabling the policy:

> Specifies whether to allow websites to make requests to more-private
> network endpoints in an insecure manner

As it looks to be a bug that they are patching hopefully that is a temporary work around.